# Duplication in css selectors, SCSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, compass-sass, sass

Let's say I have such style definitions:

```
.a.b   { ... }
.a.b.c { ... }
```

Is there a way to avoid `.a.b` part duplication using SASS/SCSS?

Comment: @BoltClock: oh, `compass` tag was autocompleted to `-geolocation`, that's weird )

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147784/160410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nest the `.a.b.c` rule within `.a.b` and replace the first part with the [`&` combinator](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_):

```
.a.b {
    ...
    &.c { ... }
}
```

Comment: Can you please refer to the documentation?

Comment: @zerkms: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_

Comment: 36 seconds... not [my fastest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended/5455770#5455770) at all :)

Comment: @BoltClock: stackoverflow should have a badge for that - for the answers that have been checked and didn't have modifications after 30 seconds (1 minutes) after question has been posted.

Comment: @zerkms: `Bolt Clock` silver badge?

Comment: @o.v.: `zerkms badge` - as long as I proposed to add it ;-P