# Escaping double quotes in CSS selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html tag,

```
<div style="background-image: url("resources/images/test.jpg");"/>
```

I want to target this element using CSS selector. I tried below selector but its throwing error,

```
document.querySelector('*[style*="background-image: url("resources/images/test.jpg")"]')

Error: DOM Exception: SYNTAX_ERR (12)
```

I somehow have to escape double quotes around "resources/images/test.jpg". Please let me know if there is anyway I can escape it and target the tag.

Comment: `I somehow have to escape double quotes around "resources/images/test.jpg"` no need double quote there. you can remove it.

Comment: Its not necessary to add double quotes inside your url.

Comment: Not use quotes or use singlequotes and scape in the javascript with \ so `document.querySelector('*[style*="background-image: url(\'resources/images/test.jpg\')"]')`

Comment: Why downvote ? The problem is well explained !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not just in your selector string but also in your markup. The quotes in the `url()` value are interfering with the `style` attribute value resulting in invalid HTML. ([The `/>` bit is invalid as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended/5455770#5455770) but that's not really relevant.)

Since you're dealing with a `url()` value you can simply drop the quotes:

```
<div style="background-image: url(resources/images/test.jpg);">
```

Then amend your selector accordingly:

```
document.querySelector('*[style*="background-image: url(resources/images/test.jpg)"]');
```

On a side note I highly recommend trying to identify the element some other way, e.g. by using a class or constructing a selector based on the structure of your markup, instead of targeting the `style` attribute, which is fragile. If you still need to test this style, you should just query the element's computed styles using `window.getComputedStyle()` on the element after selecting it, since it's very likely that the inline style will be used.

If you cannot edit the markup, and what you have given in your question is exactly how it appears, then unfortunately you have invalid markup and it will be impossible for you to match this element, even with a valid selector.

---

If you absolutely must have the double quotes in the `url()` value, you have a few options:

- HTML-encode the inner quotes:

  ```
  <div style="background-image: url(&quot;resources/images/test.jpg&quot;);">
  ```
- Or swap the outer double quotes with single quotes so you don't have to HTML-encode anything:

  ```
  <div style='background-image: url("resources/images/test.jpg");'>
  ```

To use the double quotes within the attribute selector:

- You need to escape them twice: once for the selector, and again so it doesn't break the JavaScript string:

  ```
  document.querySelector('*[style*="background-image: url(\\"resources/images/test.jpg\\")"]');
  ```
- Alternatively, you can swap the quotes as above, although you will still need to escape the inner double quotes once so they don't break the string:

  ```
  document.querySelector("*[style*='background-image: url(\"resources/images/test.jpg\")']");
  ```

You can also use single quotes in the `url()` value, in which case you would need to follow the steps above, swapping the quotes as appropriate (except there is no need to HTML-encode anything). But as you can see, it's extremely complicated; if you can edit the markup, I'd honestly just drop the quotes entirely and avoid all of this.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that if one **really** needs to escape single quotes, it can be done using `\'` and double quotes using `\"`.

Comment: @Sir Celsius: It's not as simple as that, actually. I didn't want to go into that at all because doing so would double the length of my answer.

Comment: I get it that the OP's syntax isn't correct, but I'd be interested in knowing why escaping quotes isn't.

Comment: @Sir Celsius: Well I'll try to explain it in an addendum, hopefully it won't be too convoluted.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this instead:

```
<div style="background-image: url(resources/images/test.jpg);"></div>
```

you don't need to have the quotes around the file path of your image

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use quotes, however if you need one you can always use single quotes '

Answer (score 0):

The div tag that shows up in HTML is not under my control so I can't remove the quotes in url. Anyway based @Pedro comments below selector worked for me,

```
document.querySelector("*[style*='background-image: url(\"resources/images/test.jpg\")']")
```

I'm writing scripts in Selenium so it is necessary for me to target the image divs based on its source.

Comment: Your selector cannot possibly work - the HTML is malformed and there is no way you could ever target it correctly, even with a valid selector. If your selector does work, then the HTML you have given in the question is inaccurate.

Comment: Yes correct. HTML I have provided is incomplete. HTML I'm getting in  the page very large so I had to cut it short before posting the question.