# How to escape a single quote on a data attribute jquery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

Imagine that we have this HTML structure:

```
<main>
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div data-type="John 'phil',15">Light</div>
</main>
```

I would like to select the element using its `data-type` however when I try my code gives me an error:

```
let aliasScape = alias.replace(/['.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); //alias is "John 'phil',15"
$("[data-type =| '" + aliasScape + "']")
```

> expression not recognized [data-type =| 'John 'phil',15']

Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping double quotes in CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443917/escaping-double-quotes-in-css-selector)

Comment: You can also use [`jQuery.escapeSelector()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

Comment: Sorry for delay. Exactly, finally I used the $.scapeSelector() it was more clear to other teammates and the propouse, thanks for the interest ;)

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the selector you can provide a function to `filter()` which matches directly using the `data()` method. This way you don't need to mess around escaping the value to work in a selector:

```js
let alias = "John 'phil',15";
var $elements = $("[data-type]").filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('type') == alias;
});

console.log($elements.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div data-type="John 'phil',15">Light</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing selector with single quotes and [`|=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) instead of `=|`

```js
let alias = "John 'phil',15"
console.log($('[data-type|="' + alias + '"]')[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div data-type="John 'phil',15">Light</div>
</main>
```