# How to capture the text value of following code?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to get the following text value of 50000 using xpath:

```
 <span class="XYZ">
    <span class="Value"/>
   50000
 </span>
```

I tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[@class='xyz'])).getText()
```

but its not working.

Comment: XML and XPath are case sensitive. Try changing `xyz` to `XYZ`

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455770/2386700

`<span class="Value"/>`
is invalid HTML. So you'll get some unexpected behavior.

Using Chrome, inspect this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kqta82pd/

You'll see that Chrome automatically tries to correct the HTML for you. It removes the `\>` and adds a closing `</span>` tag.

So your 5000 is now contained within the `<span class="Value">` element.

So the following selector should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[@class='Value'])).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is correct but its value should be "XYZ" not "xyz" incorrect try this:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[@class='xyz'])).getText()
```

or use

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[contains(text(),'50000')])).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the /> of second span is incorrect, I think you desired shoud like this:

```
<span class="XYZ">
    <span class="Value">30000</span>
   50000
 </span>
```

Below xpath can directly choose the 5000 from html code snippet I give out at above.

```
//span[@class='XYZ']/text()[contains(., '5000')]
```