# My absolute positioned div is covering my other div despite lower z-index

Tags: html, css

This is so strange that I can't even replicate the error in jsfiddle despite copy-pasting the code.

Basically I have it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="absolute-background" />
    <div class="where-is-this" />
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.container {
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.absolute-background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

.where-is-this {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000000;
  background: red;
}
```

This should display a red box at the top of the screen, as it does in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmj6d625/

However, in my actual page (on the same browser) the blue covers EVERYTHING. I can even add new `div`s below with text and they are completely hidden.

Screenshot:

[Where is my div?!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShOB.png)

Anyone have any suggestions how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: position:relative to the red box

Comment: All I can say is that `z-index` does not apply if no alternate positioning has been applied (aka `relative` or `absolute` instead of `static`)

Comment: `div` elements are _not_ self-closing e.g. don't do this: `<div />`. Because you've done this, `.where-is-this` is _inside_ `.absolute-background`. The browser is making it's best guess as to what you want due to incorrect HTML syntax.

Comment: @chazsolo Not true, is it? Look at the screenshot.

Comment: @SophieD look at the rendered code instead in the fiddle - elements are nested, not siblings.

Comment: @chazsolo That's what the screenshot shows. They are not nested.

Comment: The code in your screenshot and the rendered elements in the jsFiddle are different. Go into your jsfiddle and change your elements to `<div></div>` and you'll see the red element disappears.

Comment: @SophieD, use position :relative for the class .where-is-this and also provided screenshot of inspected element - .absolute-background

Comment: @chazsolo Yep just saw that. Wow! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index property only works on elements with a position value other than static (e.g. position: absolute;, position: relative;, or position: fixed).

There is also position: sticky; that is supported in Firefox, is prefixed in Safari, worked for a time in older versions of Chrome under a custom flag, and is under consideration by Microsoft to add to their Edge browser.
Thanks to Evert for this answer

Answer (score 0):

1.) DIV Tags can't be self closing

2.) You need a height for the `body` tag, otherwise it will have 0 height, and that will also apply to `container` and `.absolute-background`, making them invisible.

3.) You need `position: absolute` or `position: relative` for the `z-index` of the red DIV to become effective (`fixed` would also work, but then it wouldn't scroll with the rest of the page)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.absolute-background {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

.where-is-this {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000000;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="absolute-background"></div>
  <div class="where-is-this"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be `absolute` positioned. Your first point is wrong, and I do have a 100% height on body and html.

Comment: well, if you are convinced about that (i.e. self-closing DIV tags), good luck to you ;-)

Comment: You seem to be right, and jsfiddle doesn't understand self-closing divs which is why it showed up there but on my page the self-closing tags worked, which is why nothing showed up. Geez!

Comment: For some more info on the first point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended

Comment: The "self-closing" tags you are using are just differently interpreted by different browsers, fiddles etc. which try to make the best out of it, but this way or that, they are invalid HTML