# For which version of IE is it safe to use empty element minimization (self close elements) in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm currently coding to the HTML5 spec, which allows me to close self closing elements like this:

```
<br />
```

I'm used to the xhtml spec and would like to continue to use this convention, but I have reason to be concerned about viewers with some fairly old browsers and am interested to know where IE picks up support for it.

Perhaps unsupported browsers ignore the space and forward slash anyway and my concern is unnecessary?

Comment: Have you been serving your XHTML as `application/xhtml+xml`? If not, then changing your Doctype isn't going to make any difference in which browsers you've been supporting.

Comment: @Quentin I have always served it as XHTML, but done so selectively via PHP so that versions of IE prior to 8 render it well.  For those pages that receive the XHTML version, my pages have no doctype, as the browsers ignore them when rendering as xml anyway.  Here I'm primarily trying to find out if my xhtml habits are wholly backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML syntax (HTML serialization) for HTML5, the notation `<br/>` is allowed, for compatibility, and means the same as `<br>`. Any amount of white space characters are allowed between the tag name and the slash. In XHTML syntax for HTML5, all XML rules are enforced, but you are probably not using HTML5 genuinely as XHTML, with an XHTML content type, since that would imply that the page does not display at all on IE 8 and older.

When processing HTML (as opposite to processing genuine XHTML), all browsers currently in use ignore the slash in `<br/>`, whether or not a space intervenes. According to the approved answer to question [Is it still necessary to put a space before closing an empty element in XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305431/is-it-still-necessary-to-put-a-space-before-closing-an-empty-element-in-xhtml/) the last browser to require the space was Netscape 4, but according to a comment there, it was really Netscape 3. Apparently no version of IE ever required it. In any case, even that was about the necessity of the *space*; there does not seem to be any evidence of a browser that would have had difficulties with ignoring the *slash* in tags like `<br />`.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually do deal XHTML5 selectively by using PHP to check the HTTP_ACCEPT header.  The script I'm using is quite old, though, and I'm learning that I may or may not be using the HTTP_ACCEPT method correctly.  It also contains a function to format out the space and forward slash when dealing as text/html.  This seemed unnecessary, thus the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

Every version! You can do it with every version.